# Flask WTForms dynamic select field from list instead of db

Tags: python, flask, dropdown, flask-wtforms

I am attempting to create a dynamic drop down (SelectField) with WTForms. I have read the documentation and have looked at quite a few answers on stack, and all of the examples involve iterating over a db query.

I simply want to iterate over a list (that's generated from an external API call) to inject the SelectField choices. For example:

```
class ToolForm(FlaskForm):


    myField3 = SelectField(u'Select Account', choices=[], coerce=int)


@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    form = ToolForm()
    accounts5 = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Select Account':

            #code that generates list called "accounts5"

            acctchoices = [(c.id,c.name) for c in accounts5]
            form.myField3.choices = acctchoices

    return render_template('test.html', title='test', form=form, accounts5=accounts5)
```

And my relevant HTML looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.myField3.label(class="form-control-label") }} {% if form.myField3.errors %} {{ 
    form.myField3(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {% for errors in form.myField3.errors %}
        <span>{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% else %} {{ form.myField3(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} {% endif %}
</div>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/test" method="post">


    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" name="submit_button" value="Select Account">

</form>
```

When I click "Select Account" I get an `'int' object has no attribute 'id'` error. I thought this might be a data type issue so I tried with a list of strings but to no avail.

My question is, how can I populate my SelectField from a list?

Comment: What does accounts5 look like? Are you sure it comes with 'id' and 'name' that you can access?

Comment: @Till Accounts5 looks like a normal list, which I realize now was an oversight. I tried building a list with tuples like `accounts5 = [("test", '1'), ("tested", '3'), ("testing", '3')]` but got `'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Ok, in this list you've switched the ID and the Name for the SelectField. Why don't you try to simplify your logic first and get a SelectField working? If you set `accounts5 = [('1', 'test'), ('3','tested'),('4','testing')]` and `form.myField3.choices = accounts5` then it will work. The list you're showing doesn't have an 'id' or 'name' attribute for a primary key (the database object you've taken the example from does though).

Answer (score 3):

When you `GET` that route it will load a form that is generic and render it to the page, without any `myField3` choices having been set or available.

You can control the form to load based on certain criteria by using the `__init__` override:

```
class ToolForm(FlaskForm):
    myField3 = SelectField(u'Select Account', choices=[], coerce=int)
    def __init__(self, accounts=None):
        super().__init__()  # calls the base initialisation and then...
        if accounts: 
            self.myField3.choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in accounts]
```

Then you will construct the form from some other information based on the route request:

```
   @app.route("/test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def test():
       # define accounts
       form = ToolForm(accounts=accounts)
```

Comment: This was an interesting answer and gave me some new ideas, but I still get the same error `'int' object has no attribute 'id` and when I changed it to a tuple I got `'tuple' object has no attribute 'id`

Comment: As @Till says just use `self.myField.choices = accounts`. Only `classes` can identify attributes using a `.`. like `c.id` otherwise you index a tuple by index, i.e. `c[0]` and `c[1]`. This error is related to a separate problem of you not defining `accounts` correctly according to how you want to populate choices.